# Generating a pseudo-random character in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, random, x86, nasm

I'm learning assembly, and I found this code:

```
; Initialized seed value
    xor [myseed], esp

    ; Generate random string
    call randletter
    mov [message], al       ; Write 1st letter

; myrand gives a pseudo-random number in range 0..max
; inputs:
;   edi - max value
; outputs:
;   eax - generated value
myrand: mov eax, [myseed]       ; Load state of generator
        mov ecx, 4000000001 
        mul ecx                 ; Multiply state var by a constant
        add eax, 3333333333     ; Add another constant
        mov [myseed], eax       ; And save the result
        xor edx, edx
        inc edi
        div edi                 ; Divide state var in edx:eax by (max+1) in edi
        mov eax, edx            ; div instruction writes remainder into edx, so copy to eax
        ret

; randletter gives a random lowercase letter
; inputs: no
; outputs:
;   al - random lowercase letter (ASCII code)
randletter:
        mov edi, 25
        call myrand
        add al, 'a'
        ret


    section    .data

myseed: dd  123456789
```

Now I know that, this is linear congruential generator in the method `myrand`.
My question is how the number from `myrand` can cause the number from 97 to 122 in ASCII in `randletter`? And why they have `add al, a` in `myrand`. How can that help?

Comment: `myrand` is between 0 and 25, `add al, 'a'` (which is `add al, 97`) shifts the range up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASCII codes for the lowercase letters vary from 97 for 'a' to 122 for 'z'.
The output from `myrand`(25) is from 0 to 25.

```
randletter:
        mov edi, 25
        call myrand    ; -> EAX == [0,25]
        add al, 'a'    ; -> AL == [0,25] + 97 == [97,122] == ['a','z']
        ret
```

No matter the value in *myseed*, the division `div edi` will, given that `EDI=25+1`, always produce a remainder from 0 to 25. This remainder becomes the result of the *myrand* function.

```
EDI=25
        ...
        mov [myseed], eax   ; And save the result
        xor edx, edx        ; EDX=0
        inc edi             ; -> EDI == 25 + 1 == 26
        div edi             ; Divide EDX:EAX by 26 -> remainder EDX == [0,25]
        mov eax, edx        ; return result in EAX
        ret
```

The calculation that leads to the new value of *myseed* is only important for the quality of the distribution of the random numbers.
The restriction of the output range is exclusively obtained from taking the **remainder of the division**.

Comment: The remainder from a division is always smaller than the divisor. The *myrand* function increments the input before the division so that the input can become the highest output value.